# How can I securely store the scripts for my cronjobs?

Tags: php, cron

I have a PHP script, that goes through all users in a database and deletes every account that has not been activated and whose activation code sent by email has expired. My question is not so much about the script itself but about cronjobs. I want that PHP script to run once everyday and I understand how you set up cronjobs but my question is this: Where do I put my script? I obviously don't want it to be accessible to any user of the website only to the cronjobs on my server. So I probably wouldn't wanna put it in the root directory of my website. What I was thinking is that perhaps it would work if I put it inside the root folder of my webspace where the root folder for my website is located as well.[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4OP9.png) shows my webspace. 'Portfolio' is the root of a website that has an actual domain name assigned to it.

Comment: Just don't deploy the script inside the www root directory. Which is that www root directory depends on the host OS and the webserver you use (Apache, Nginx, etc..)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to put the script in the dummy folder in your root directory. and simply change the permission of that folder so that no one can open the folder or its content by just browsing it...